# Xcode build fails using RestKit and AFNetworking via Cocoapods after a copy target

Tags: ios, xcode6, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have returned to a fairly large project that uses RestKit and many other libraries. 
The existing target builds and archives fine. Xcode 6.4, SDK iOS 8.4, target iOS 7.0.

I did this:

1. Duplicated the existing target.
2. Added some pre-processor macros and a different product name
3. Expected the new target to build and archive successfully.

Now the build fails with:
(null): Library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking

NOTES:

- I have compared the raw target details and they are identical apart from the few changes I noted above.
- I don't really want to run `pod install` on the project. Why? Because I'm afraid, yes. And because I don't want to spend much time - I just need to make a variant build and then move on to something else. A pod install after a period away could cause unwanted breakage.
- I have had this problem before on the very same project, and yes I am cursing the former me for not making better notes at the time, but the former me says that he was fatigued and pissed off with it at the time and couldn't bear another minute, and knew it would come back to bite the later me in the arse.

So now before I bang my head against this again, I am hoping a kind and generous soul reading this will share a golden path of light that leads up and away from the pain directly to the promised land of a clean build.

Comment: Your pod should link to explicit versions if you're worried about needing to reinstall. Not sure why the target didn't duplicate cleanly though, I don't recall seeing that before...

Comment: True thanks for the comment. There are about 15 or so entries in there so I'd need to go through and set them all.